# What are differences between various indexing service: SCI, SSCI, SCOPUS and others?

Tags: publications, journals, online-learning, distance-learning, indexing

I wanted to submit a paper to "Computer & Education (IF: 3.819 and indexed in many other indexing system)" journal by Elsevier, but unfortunately submitted a paper to "The Internet and Higher Education (IF 4.238 and indexed in few services compared to previous journal)" journal by Elsevier. I have only checked the impact factor and ranking of journal in the ICT and education domain but forgot to reconfirm whether it is indexed in SCI or SSCI.

My most of the peers talk about the SCI and SSCI papers, and they ignore SCOPUS indexing papers. My paper that I submitted to "The Internet and Higher Education" has already gone for review process. Is there any way to get rid of it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "get rid of it"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lot of questions embedded in your question. Follow the following links:

- [Difference between SCOPUS and Web of Science](http://hlwiki.slais.ubc.ca/index.php/Scopus_vs._Web_of_Science)
- [What is the difference between SCI and SCIE?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26656/what-is-the-difference-between-sci-and-scie)
- [SSCI-Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Sciences_Citation_Index)

Googling further would result in more comprehensive answers. See the related question on the right-hand side of your academia SE page.

> My paper that I submitted to "The Internet and Higher Education" has already gone for review process. Is there any way to get rid of it?

Answer is YES and NO. YES: You can write email to editor and ask for withdrawal. NO: You should not do it.