# Reliable method to find ISI rated Journal

Tags: journals, web-of-science

I searched in internet and all I found was that we have to search the name of journal in "https://mjl.clarivate.com/" and if it indexed as: SCIE or SSCI or ESCI then the journal is indexed as ISI journal.
but I wanted to submit my paper in "https://academic.oup.com/painmedicine" and I serached it in clarivate and it said that it is indexed as SCIE. But when I email to the editor of painmedicine journal he said that their journal is not rated or indexed as ISI. Now I am very confused that which journal is ISI?

Comment: Various unneeded comments were removed here (by multiple moderators); let us remember to [be nice](https://academia.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach you found - that of looking for the journal in the [Master Journal List](https://mjl.clarivate.com/) of Web of Science (WoS) - is the correct one. *Pain Medicine* is indeed indexed in SCIE and thus in one of WoS' databases.

Note that WoS was originally created by *ISI* (Institute for Scientific Information), but is now curated by *Clarivate Analytics*. Thus, the label of an "ISI-rated journal" is not entirely correct, and it is possible that due to this incorrect label, the person with whom you corresponded did not understand what you meant.

Comment: Thank you so much. What are the other abbrevation like SCIE means that a paper is belong to WoS database? For example SCI or ESCI and etc

Comment: SCI, SCIE, SSCI, ESCI - they all belong to Web of Science. The four abbreviations denote four different databases (or indexes) *within* the overarching platform WoS. See also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/127695/is-there-any-relation-between-them-like-esci-is-less-than-scie-and-scie-is-less?rq=1 for some details, if that helps.