# How to get an updated list of SCI journals?

Tags: journals, indexing

The Science Citation Index(SCI) is a citation index originally produced by the Institute for Scientific Information (ISI). Currently, the indexing is done by by Clarivate Analytics.
But, currently only the list of SCIE journals are provided by Clarivate Analytics via [Web of Science](https://mjl.clarivate.com/home) (along with a few other indices). Hence, the question
**How to get an updated list of SCI journals?**

Also, I would like to know whether there is a quality assurance difference between SCI and SCIE presently. If there is no difference in terms of quality, then that means SCIE has practically replaced SCI and the above question (in bold) would be irrelevant.

Comment: @Arno. I am afraid not. The problem is that the top two answers to the linked question ([1](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/32099/91305) and [2](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/71117/91305)) are at odds (e.g.: according to one answer, the only major difference is the storage media).

Comment: @Arno. Oh, they are not at odds really. The other answer also says "This is because of the constraints of the CDROM and print media there is no difference in the selection process for Science Citation Index and Science Citation Index Expanded journals". Then, there is no qualitative difference between the two. So, yes, this is practically a duplicate question. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you worried about SCIE and SCI? The difference lies in how the documents are saved. Both SCI and SCIE are considered possessing to he highest possible standards of quality.

Regarding the updated list, kindly go to the master journal list section to see the list.

Comment: In the master journal list, only list of SCIE journals is available now (but not list of SCI journals). I am worried about the difference because our institute has conditions on the number of SCI journals before we submit our PhD thesis.

Comment: In case your institute accepts papers published in SCI journals, it will accept those published in SCIE too. The difference lies in storage, not in quality or standards.